# Spring boot not overriding Exception using @ControllerAdvice

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to have a standard custom exception thrown from the controller advice aspect but for some reason my custom exception is not being caught by spring boot (1.3.3-RELEASE).

This is the code I have:

My Test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(MyApplication.class)
@WebIntegrationTest("server.port:9000") 
public class ControllerTest {
    private final String URL = "http://localhost:9000";

    @Test
    public void testCustomExceptionResponse() {
        // Invoke my controller generating some exception
        Map error = restTemplate.getForObject(URL+"/exception/", Map.class);
        assertTrue(error.get("exception").contains("MyCustomException"));
    }
}
```

The controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Object> findAll() throws Exception {
    // generate whatever exception here
    if (1<2) throw new IllegalIdentifierException("test whatever exception");
    return ccRepository.findByActive(true);
}
```

The GlobalExceptionHandler annotated with @ControllerAdvice

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalExceptionHandler.class);

    // Catch whatever exception to throw my custom exception
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public void handleException(Exception ex) throws Exception {
        logger.error("Exception Occured: ", ex);
        throw new MyCustomException(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

I have debugged the code and the handleException method is being executed, however the weird thing is that MyCustomException is being thrown but the controller response is returning the original exception thrown:

```
{timestamp=1473963128439, status=500, error=Internal Server Error, exception=org.hibernate.metamodel.relational.IllegalIdentifierException, message=test whatever exception, path=/exception/}
```

I'm expecting to have something like this:

```
exception=com.myapp.MyCustomException
```

As far as I know, the controller advice is the generic way to catch all the exceptions in the controllers to have some logic tied (which in my case is the logger) and then I customized the unexpected exceptions by using a custom one.

Am I missing anything about how Spring Boot handles the exceptions?

Comment: Are you using the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` runner with the test?

Comment: @ChrisThompson, yes, have just updated the test with that

Comment: in the test you are asking for `/exception`, but the log says `path=/creditcards/` so maybe you are looking at the wrong part of the log? or the routing is not correct?

Comment: @tonakai, sorry... I have copy/paste/modified and forgot to modify the log.

Comment: @PauChorro didn't work

Comment: You are handling the error yourself so Spring Boot has nothing else to do. Throwing an exception from something that is supposed to "handle the exception" is weird as well.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll the weird thing is that spring is hanlding the exception by putting the original but not overriding mine. Since this is a controller advice I want just to log the error into a file and then let spring boot to carry on. Which actually it does but not with the exception I throw. I don't want to create a full error objects since I want to leverage the current spring boot support. Not sure if I'm missing something... do you think that is weird? Btw, if I don't throw the new exception, then I receive null in the response, so that's why I throw mine

Comment: @StephaneNicoll, so there is no feature to do what I want? Would the right way be to return a ResponseEntity with a CustomError object?

Comment: If you are handling the exception, you are handling it, you're not asking Spring Boot to "carry on". Returning a response entity is one good way, no need to have a custom error object though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not exactly the purpose of ControllerAdvice.

### What is happening

- you throw IllegalIdentifierException
- you catch it in your ControllerAdvice
- your handleException does not finish since you throw MyCustomException
- this raises an exception in DispatcherServlet, with your original exception (IllegalIdentifierException) as root cause.

### What you should do

The Controller Advice is meant to return a valid Http response in case of an error.

For instance, you could change it to:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleException(Exception ex) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Exception Occured: " + ex);
        return ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .body("Exception: " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

Thus:

- the ControllerAdvice's method would complete successfully (returning a response);
- The DispatcherServlet would be happy with you.
- The original exception wouldn't be the root cause of a new error and is now swallowed successfully
- the client receives the message "Exception: test whatever exception" with an HTTP Error code (I picked HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).

You can test it with `MockMvc`:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(Launcher.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
    
    @Test
    public void testCustomExceptionResponse() throws Exception {
        MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
        
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/your/uri"))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isInternalServerError())
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().string("Exception: test whatever exception"));
        
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll mark this as resolved since it actually taught me the right behaviour. However, I found a different approach to solve my problem by overriding ErrorAttributes. I just override the exception if some specific things happens and I think it's better than using ControllerAdivce. What do you think

Answer (score 0):

I've just created a sample project based on your code, try to change this line:

```
Map error = restTemplate.getForObject("/exception/", Map.class);
```

to

```
Map error = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:9000/", Map.class);
```

since your `RequestMapping` is looking for `/` I think some other method is handling your http request, that explains the hibernate error message as well, since `1<2` return true all the time.

My logs look like this:

```
2016-09-15 22:21:32.101 ERROR 7688 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] tonakai.GlobalExceptionHandler       : Exception Occured: 

tonakai.IllegalIdentifierException: test whatever exception
    at tonakai.SampleController.findAll(SampleController.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not solving the problem. If you check the object Map error in the test case, you will have the exception field with IllegalIdentifierException and it should have MyCustomException. The thing is that this `assertTrue(error.get("exception").contains("MyCustomExceptio‌​n"));` is not working