# Define custom error message in REST using Spring on Weblogic

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, weblogic-10.x

I am hosting Spring Boot app on weblogic 10.3.6 for REST api
I'd like to implement these 2 features:

1. Whenever my custom exception occurs I would like to send a http response with message e.g. 500 - "request couldn't be parsed because of something..."
2. Whenever any error is thrown I would like to get the stack trace that is usually printed to console (for debugging purposes)

I tried to solve the first part the following way:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerAdvice {


    @ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
    public ResponseEntity handleException(MyException e) {

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(e.getMessage());
    }
```

However as a response I only get 500 Internal Server Error with no message

As for the second part I tried simmilar approach but there was no error message either.

How can I solve this?

EDIT:
The best I could achieve was removing ExceptionHandlerAdvice and using annotation on my exception class instead like this:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, reason="This is a message I'd like to send")
```

It works, but I have to add some variables from code to the message and this method does not allow it

EDIT2: 
This is a bit weird, perhaps a behavior of weblogic server, but when I set the httpStatus to HttpStatus.ACCEPTED I can see the message, if it is HttpStatus.Forbidden or any other 4xx error I just get the error without message

Comment: Hello Zerg, Terran here. Maybe your service throw exception that not in control of ExceptionHandlerAdvice, try to debug and print to console with system.out

Comment: I am purposedly throwing MyException in one method: throw new MyException("some message");

Comment: Hello zerg, try throws Exception in handleException method. Ref here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39517876/spring-boot-not-overriding-exception-using-controlleradvice?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create '[ResponseEntity](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html)' object with message and status and return it, it will display with error message.

```
/**
 * HTTP_STATUS - 500 -Service Unavailable.
 * 
 * @param exception
 *            Catches the following: MyException
 * @return
 */
@ExceptionHandler({ MyException.class})
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
@ResponseBody
public static ResponseEntity<?> handleConnectionErrorResponse(MyException exception) {
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("Some error occurred at server", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

Comment: This still does not give me nothing more than 500 Internal Server Error without error message

Comment: I am not able to get message whenever I send an error, when I use HttpStatus.ACCEPTED I see the message, any ideas?

Comment: Didn't face that issue, Not sure what caused that.

Comment: I will just send the messages with accept status and this solves my problem, your answer was the most helpful

Answer (score 0):

Do not return something, throw an :

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
public class UnprocessableEntity extends RuntimeException {

    public UnprocessableEntity(String string) {
        super(string);
    }

}
```

Or another thing like that.

Comment: even if I use @ResponseStatus annotation, and add reason parameter like:
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, reason="A message I would like to print")
I cannot pass parameters from code to the error message so this is not the answer

Comment: `String msg = "YOUR MESSAGE FROM YOUR CODE"; throw new UnprocessableEntity(msg);`
By the way `UnprocessableEntity` is a n custom `Exception`, it mean you can build your own as long as you extends `RuntimeException`.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am doing and it does not return message, only the status code like 500, 422 etc

Comment: Ok, you want your message as text in the body of the response ; not as an error message.

Answer (score 0):

I also went through the same requirement. 
Below is the code which is working for me:

```
String errMsg = "{\"errorMessage\":\"Parking Slot is not available\"}";
return new ResponseEntity<String>(errMsg, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
```

Whereas `errMsg` should be written in the format which you want. Like I had requirment for response in JSON.

Hope this will help some of you

Answer (score 0):

Well In my case I have done custom error handling logic.

1. We can define a custom Base Response class wich accepts generic type(Eg: user desired model)
2. Return BaseResponse as a response for each REST Methods
   (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, etc)

> BaseResponse.java

```
public class BaseResponse<T> {
int statusCode;
String message;
T data;

public int getStatusCode() {
    return statusCode;
}

public BaseResponse<T> getValidResponse(String message, T data) {
    BaseResponse<T> baseResponse = new BaseResponse<T>();
    baseResponse.statusCode = 200;
    baseResponse.message = message;
    baseResponse.data = data;
    return baseResponse;
}

public BaseResponse<T> getErrorResponse(int StatusCode, String message) {
    BaseResponse<T> baseResponse = new BaseResponse<T>();
    baseResponse.statusCode = StatusCode;
    baseResponse.message = message;
    return baseResponse;
}

public void setStatusCode(int statusCode) {
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public T getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(T data) {
    this.data = data;
}
}
```

> User.java

```
public class User {
    String userName;
    String userAddress;
    String userEmail;
    String userPhoneNumber;
    ... 
    //Getters & Setters
}
```

> YourController.java

```
....
    @PostMapping("/addUser")
    public BaseResponse<User> addUser(User user) {
        if (user.getUserName() != null && !user.getUserName().equals("")) {
        UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();
        userEntity.setName(user.getUserName());
        ...
        userRepository.save(userEntity);
        return new BaseResponse<User>().getValidResponse("Successfully Added User", user);
        } else {
             return new BaseResponse<User>().getErrorResponse(400, "Name field is required");
        }
    }
...
    @DeleteMapping("/deleteUser/{userId}")
    //Using ? for uncertain Response.Eg: Some response might have data response and some may not have data response...
    public BaseResponse<?> deleteUser(@PathVariable(value = "userId") int userId) {
         //After delete operation...we don't require data response.
         return new BaseResponse<User>().getValidResponse("Successfully deleted the User", null);

    }
```

This might not be an exact solution for the question asked but will surely help someone else.